# CSS grid layout that automatically adds rows and sets column width to max grid item width

Tags: css, css-grid

I'd like a grid layout with an arbitrary number of grid items that automatically creates a new row when one is filled, kind of like:

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 256px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(75px, 1fr));
}

#grid span {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id=grid>
  <span>content 1</span>
  <span>content 2</span>
  <span>content 3</span>
  <span>content 4</span>
  <span>content 5</span>
  <span>content 6</span>
  <span>content 7</span>
  <span>content 8</span>
  <span>content 9</span>
  <span>content 10</span>
</div>
```

The problem is I don't want to have to hard-code that `75px`. **Is there a way to set that value to "the content width of the widest grid item"?**

I've tried changing `75px` to `min-content`, which [seems like it'd work from the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#min-content), but the dev tools says that's invalid CSS. I've also tried just setting `grid-auto-columns: min-content` instead of `grid-template-columns`, and that seems to set the width correctly, but each grid item takes up an entire row.

Comment: no, it's not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. But it’s a good question, and I think this is a common use case which really ought to be supported.

You’ll find the details of what’s currently supported in the spec for [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns). The relevant section for **auto-repeat** is

```
<auto-repeat> = 
  repeat( [ auto-fill | auto-fit ] , [ <line-names>? <fixed-size> ]+ <line-names>? )
```

where **fixed-size** is

```
<fixed-size> = 
  <fixed-breadth>                                   |
  minmax( <fixed-breadth> , <track-breadth> )       |
  minmax( <inflexible-breadth> , <fixed-breadth> )
```

and the other bits are

```
<track-breadth> = 
  <length-percentage>  |
  <flex>               |
  min-content          |
  max-content          |
  auto                 

<inflexible-breadth> = 
  <length-percentage>  |
  min-content          |
  max-content          |
  auto                 
    
<fixed-breadth> = 
  <length-percentage>  

<length-percentage> = 
  <length>      |
  <percentage>
```

This means that when using `minmax()` within `grid-template-columns` to generate columns automatically, **either your minimum or your maximum** needs to be a fixed length or percentage. You can use `max-content` as the first value in the minmax expression, but only if you then use a fixed length or percentage as the second value in the expression. Annoying, isn’t it? I wish I understood the reasons that this limitation exists.

Can we work around it? Is this example closer to what you’re after?

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 550px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content,18%));
  overflow: hidden;
}

#grid span {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id=grid>
  <span>content 1</span>
  <span>content 22</span>
  <span>content 333</span>
  <span>content 4444</span>
  <span>content 55555</span>
  <span>content 666666</span>
  <span>content 7777777</span>
  <span>content 88888888</span>
  <span>content 999999999</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Brett my guy thank you that's super helpful. Unfortunately when setting max-content for the first minmax arg, it seems to just set the width to the second arg, so I'll probably stick to hard-coding a reasonable min.